# Add project folder in Atom from terminal

Tags: terminal, directory, project, atom-editor

I try currently to add project folder to Atom using terminal. But I don't find any usefull documentation about this subject.

How add project folder in Atom from terminal - an Atom terminal or external terminal ?

[image]
*Atom editor, at bottom we can see the platformio ide terminal...*

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `--add`/ `-a` flag to add a folder to an already open Atom session.

**Examples:**

```
# add current folder to Atom
atom -a .

# add specific path to Atom
atom -a full/path/to/project
```

See `atom --help` for a list of all available flags.

Comment: Do you know how to open a new atom window with a desired project folder added? When I try `atom -a . -n` in the terminal on Ubuntu, nothing happens.

Comment: For a new window, use `atom -n <folder>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a terminal at all unless you chose to. From the atom display select, under the file menu, add project folder. This opens a window where you can choose from existing folders or create a new one.

Comment: yes it's for a shortcut purpose but you are right too for those who want use the file management system

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the cli for atom, all you to do is go to the path of the folder you want to add and in your terminal `atom .` will open atom with the folder.